# how to display image from mysql using PDO

Tags: php

my code for my site is

```
$sth = $con->query("SELECT * FROM posts");
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC);
while($row = $sth->fetch()){
    $title = $row['post_title'];
$date = $row['post_date'];
$author = $row['post_author'];
$image = $row['post_image'];
$content = $row['post_content'];
echo "<h1>" . $row['post_title'] . "</h1>";
echo "<p>Published on: " . "<b>" . $row['post_date'] , "<p>Published By: ". $row['post_author'] ."</b>"  . "</p>";
```

How do i display my image that is in mysql database?
I am a newly learner for web developing so please help me and also guide me

Answer (score 1):

Outputting image is usually done with `img` tag. Path to image is in `src` attribute.

So, if your `$row['post_image']` stores a path to image, start with

```
echo '<img src="' . $row['post_image'] . '" />';
```

Comment: it does'n show my image in my webpage only show its image name

Comment: Open generated html and see what you have there